How to determine the user in a python script (ran by supervisord)
I have a python script that is started by supervisor. In supervisor's myapp.conf I have set the user=app_api as the user the script should be run under.
supervisor's myapp.conf :
[program:api]
directory=/opt/apps/myapp
user=app_api

I've ran into trouble with file permission errors so on investigating, I find that the script still thinks it's running as root.
import getpass
current_user = getpass.getuser()
print(current_user) # This returns root as the current user

However, if I check who is running the script in linux, I get app_api
$ps aux | grep gunicorn
32652 app_api   0:00 {gunicorn} /opt/apps/venv/app-env/bin/python /opt/apps/venv/app-env/bin/gunicorn --timeout 200 --workers 1 --bind=unix:/tmp/myapp.sock server.wsgi:application

So which is which? Ideally I want the app to run as non root, but getpass seems to think that root is running the app. So either getpass is buggy (or I don't understand it's output) or somehow supervisor is ignoring the user=app_api parameter. But then that doesn't make sense coz ps aux shows that app_api started the script?
I also tried using pwd to confirm if the app_api user can be retrieved from the system:
import pwd
user_info = pwd.getpwnam('app_api')
print(f"userinfo: {user_info}, uid: {uid}, gid: {gid}")

This does print the expected user info. So the app_api user does exist
